# App icons missing from installed flatpak like Spotify, Simple Note in Kubuntu

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, kde, icons, flatpak

When i install an app from Flatpak the app icon is missing. If i use snap it is okay icon comes. How can i solve this issue?

Maybe it is some sort of permission related issue?

[image]

[image]

Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma 5.18.5

Answer (score 4):

The .desktop files for apps installed via flatpak are stored at `/var/lib/flatpak/app/*application_name*/current/active/files/share/applications`. If you copy the .desktop file from that location to `/usr/share/applications`, the icon should show up in your applications menu.

Comment: I had to log out and log back in. the icon on the window is still missing but at least the kde taskbar shows it correctly and I can live with that :)

Comment: Is there a way to automatically add the files there? I don't want to do this every time I install a new flatpak app, that just seems unnecessarily complex.

Answer (score 0):

you can run this onliner:

```
for f in $(find /var/lib/flatpak/app/ -depth -type f -name '*.desktop');do sudo cp -v $f /usr/share/applications/$(basename $f) ;done
```

or put a cronjob for it.